# Trouble accessing Unityplayer.log on Hololens

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, hololens

I want to see my debug statements after running an app on Hololens which are stored in the Unityplayer.log file.

I am not able to download this logfile from the Windows Device Portal after running the app.

I am not sure what is causing this problem. The following issue pops up on the browser : [This site can't be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9AT0.png).

I restarted the Hololens and also checked my internet connection. Sometimes it works and most of times it doesn't get downloaded.

**About the App**

I am using HololensforCV project files to access sensor data and want to build an application around this. More specifically I am using [ArUcodetectionHololens-Unity](https://github.com/doughtmw/ArUcoDetectionHoloLens-Unity)

I am using Hololens 1 and Unity 2019.4.7f1.

Comment: Are you sure you completely killed the app before trying to access the log file? As long as the app is only hibernated the log file is still blocked

Comment: Hi, yes I completely killed the app before checking. I also restarted the Hololens and logged in to the device portal to be double sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the project solution would not stop running in the Visual Studio when I closed the app on the Hololens. When I stopped the Deployment on the VS, I had no issue downloading the log file. In addition, sometimes the Hololens got disconnected from the internet now and then.